How to use Mathematica to find the explicit formula of expected value of minimum of multiple uniform distributions?

Clear["Global`*"];
n = 5;
$Assumptions = And[0 < a1, Apply[LessEqual, Table[Symbol["a"~StringJoin~ToString@k], {k, 1, n}]]];

expectationOfMinimumValueOfNUniformDistribution[n_] := 
  Expectation[
    x, 
    x \[Distributed] OrderDistribution[
      Table[
        UniformDistribution[{0, Symbol["a"~StringJoin~ToString@k]}], 
        {k, 1, n}
      ], 
      1
    ]
  ]  // Together // ExpandNumerator // ExpandDenominator;

result = Table[
  {k, expectationOfMinimumValueOfNUniformDistribution[k]}, 
  {k, 1, n}
];

TableForm[result, TableHeadings -> {None, {"n", "Mean"}}]


The results are correct.
It has passed these test cases:
n = 3;
a1 = 2;
a2 = 3;
a3 = 9;
Expectation[x, 
    x \[Distributed] 
     OrderDistribution[
      Table[UniformDistribution[{0, 
         Symbol["a"~StringJoin~ToString@k]}], {k, 1, n}], 1]] // 
   Together // ExpandNumerator // ExpandDenominator
(a1^3 - 2 a1^2 a2 - 2 a1^2 a3 + 6 a1 a2 a3)/(
 12 a2 a3) /. {a1 -> 2, a2 -> 3, a3 -> 9}

(* 59/81 *)




n = 3;
aSymbols = Table[Symbol["a"~StringJoin~ToString@k], {k, 1, n}];
a1 = 2;
a2 = 3;
a3 = 9;
amin = Min @@ {a1, a2, a3};
myCDF = 1 - 
  Product[1 - 1/Symbol["a"~StringJoin~ToString@k]*x, {k, 1, n}]
Integrate[D[myCDF, x]*x, {x, 0, amin}]
(* 59/81 *)

n = 4;
a1 = 2;
a2 = 3;
a3 = 9;
a4 = 10;
Expectation[x, 
    x \[Distributed] 
     OrderDistribution[
      Table[UniformDistribution[{0, 
         Symbol["a"~StringJoin~ToString@k]}], {k, 1, n}], 1]] // 
   Together // ExpandNumerator // ExpandDenominator
(-3 a1^4 + 5 a1^3 a2 + 5 a1^3 a3 - 10 a1^2 a2 a3 + 5 a1^3 a4 - 
  10 a1^2 a2 a4 - 10 a1^2 a3 a4 + 30 a1 a2 a3 a4)/(
 60 a2 a3 a4) /. {a1 -> 2, a2 -> 3, a3 -> 9, a4 -> 10}


(* 1394/2025 *)

n = 5;
a1 = 2;
a2 = 3;
a3 = 9;
a4 = 10;
a5 = 12;
Expectation[x, 
    x \[Distributed] 
     OrderDistribution[
      Table[UniformDistribution[{0, 
         Symbol["a"~StringJoin~ToString@k]}], {k, 1, n}], 1]] // 
   Together // ExpandNumerator // ExpandDenominator
(2 a1^5 - 3 a1^4 a2 - 3 a1^4 a3 + 5 a1^3 a2 a3 - 3 a1^4 a4 + 
  5 a1^3 a2 a4 + 5 a1^3 a3 a4 - 10 a1^2 a2 a3 a4 - 3 a1^4 a5 + 
  5 a1^3 a2 a5 + 5 a1^3 a3 a5 - 10 a1^2 a2 a3 a5 + 5 a1^3 a4 a5 - 
  10 a1^2 a2 a4 a5 - 10 a1^2 a3 a4 a5 + 30 a1 a2 a3 a4 a5)/(
 60 a2 a3 a4 a5) /. {a1 -> 2, a2 -> 3, a3 -> 9, a4 -> 10, a5 -> 12}

(* 15989/24300 *)


What's the explicit formula of the below code?
Clear["Global`*"];
n = 4;
a[k_] := Symbol["a"~StringJoin~ToString@k];
aSymbols = Table[a[k], {k, 1, n}];
myPDF = Sum[
  Product[(1 - x/a[j]), {j, 1, n}]/(1 - x/a[k])/a[k], {k, 1, n}]
mean = Integrate[myPDF*x, {x, 0, amin}] // Together // 
   ExpandNumerator // ExpandDenominator
mean /. {amin -> Min @@ aSymbols}


It looks like a heavy dose of FindSequenceFunction and noticing that in the numerator the coefficient of $a_1^k$ for a value of $n$ is the sum of the products of $a_2, a_3,\ldots,a_n$ taken $n-k-1$ at a time.  (Or at least something similar to that.)  Just don't have time tonight to work it out.

Sorry no time until later to fill in the details but the answer at least in terms of Mathematica code seems to be n = 7; a = Table[ToExpression["a" <> ToString[i]], {i, n}]; mean = (-1)^n  Sum[LCM @@ Range[n + 1] (-1)^i  a[[1]]^(n - i + 1)  SymmetricPolynomial[i - 1,  a[[2 ;;]]]/((n - i + 2) (n - i + 1)), {i, 1, n}]/(LCM @@ Range[n + 1] SymmetricPolynomial[n - 1, a[[2 ;;]]]) // FullSimplify .

To start investigating possible patterns look at the expectation with n = 6.
expectationOfMinimumValueOfNUniformDistribution[6] // Simplify
(* (1/(420 a2 a3 a4 a5 a6))a1 (-10 a1^5 + 210 a2 a3 a4 a5 a6 + 
   14 a1^4 (a2 + a3 + a4 + a5 + a6) - 
   21 a1^3 (a4 a5 + a4 a6 + a5 a6 + a3 (a4 + a5 + a6) + 
      a2 (a3 + a4 + a5 + a6)) - 
   70 a1 (a3 a4 a5 a6 + a2 (a3 a5 a6 + a4 a5 a6 + a3 a4 (a5 + a6))) + 
   35 a1^2 (a3 a4 a5 + a3 a4 a6 + a3 a5 a6 + a4 a5 a6 + 
      a2 (a5 a6 + a4 (a5 + a6) + a3 (a4 + a5 + a6)))) *)

We see that the denominator is a constant times a2 a3 a4 a5 a6 = SymmetricPolynomial[5,{a2, a3, a4, a5, a6}].
Looking at the denominators for n being 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, and 8 we have
  12 SymmetricFunction[2, {a2, a3, a4, a5, a6}]
  60 SymmetricFunction[3, {a2, a3, a4, a5, a6}]
  60 SymmetricFunction[4, {a2, a3, a4, a5, a6}]
 420 SymmetricFunction[5, {a2, a3, a4, a5, a6}]
 840 SymmetricFunction[6, {a2, a3, a4, a5, a6, a7}]
2520 SymmetricFunction[7, {a2, a3, a4, a5, a6, a7, a8}]

Entering 12, 60, 60, 420, 840, 2520 into https://oeis.org/ results in a function to generate those coefficients:  Least common multiple (or LCM) of {1, 2, ..., n}.
LCM @@ Range[#] & /@ {3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8}
(* {6, 12, 60, 60, 420, 840} *)

Now back to the example for n = 6.  The numerator is
a1 (-10  a1^5  SymmetricPolynomial[0, {a2, a3, a4, a5, a6}] +
     14  a1^4  SymmetricPolynomial[1, {a2, a3, a4, a5, a6}] -
     21  a1^3  SymmetricPolynomial[2, {a2, a3, a4, a5, a6}] +
     35  a1^2  SymmetricPolynomial[3, {a2, a3, a4, a5, a6}] -
     70  a1^1  SymmetricPolynomial[4, {a2, a3, a4, a5, a6}] + 
    210  a1^0  SymmetricPolynomial[5, {a2, a3, a4, a5, a6}])

Using  FindSequenceFunction  on  the  coefficients  we  have
FindSequenceFunction[{-10, 14, -21, 35, -70, 210}, i]
(* (420 (-1)^i)/((-8+i) (-7+i)) *)

Note  that  the  coefficient  of  420  is  equal  to
LCM @@ Range[6]
So looking at the results for n = 6, 7, and 8 we guess that the coefficients are generated with
(LCM @@ Range[n]  (-1)^i)/((n + 2 - i)  (n + 1 - i))

And that checks with the results.  Putting this altogether we have the following function for the expectation:
mean[n_?IntegerQ, a_] := (-1)^n Sum[LCM @@ Range[n + 1] (-1)^i a[[1]]^(n - i + 1)*
  SymmetricPolynomial[i - 1, a[[2 ;;]]]/((n - i + 2)  (n - i + 1)), {i, 1, n}]/
  (LCM @@ Range[n + 1]  SymmetricPolynomial[n - 1, a[[2 ;;]]]) // FullSimplify

mean[6, {a1, a2, a3, a4, a5, a6}]
(* (1/(420 a2 a3 a4 a5 a6))a1 (-10 a1^5 + 210 a2 a3 a4 a5 a6 + 
   14 a1^4 (a2 + a3 + a4 + a5 + a6) - 
   21 a1^3 (a4 a5 + (a4 + a5) a6 + a3 (a4 + a5 + a6) + a2 (a3 + a4 + a5 + a6)) - 
   70 a1 (a3 a4 a5 a6 + a2 (a3 a4 a5 + a4 a5 a6 + a3 (a4 + a5) a6)) + 
   35 a1^2 (a3 a4 a5 + a4 a5 a6 + a3 (a4 + a5) a6 + a2 (a4 a5 + (a4 + a5) a6 + a3 (a4 + a5 + a6)))) *)

Update:
If we let s[n_, i_] represent SymmetricPolynomial[i, Table[a[j],{j, 2, n}], then we can write the general result in a much more compact form:
m[n_] := Sum[(-1)^(i + 1)  a[1]^i  sp[n, n - i]/((i + i^2) sp[n, n - 1]), {i, 1, n}]

$$\sum _{i=1}^n \frac{(-1)^{i+1} a_1^i s(n,n-i)}{\left(i^2+i\right) s(n,n-1)}$$
